# Wordpress - Imagenes en la página de inicio para el formato móvil (responsive)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme, wordpress-imagenes, wordpress-widget

Tengo este código dentro de una **página** de mi blog con **wordpress** que es una tabla donde muestro 3 categorías con sus nombres y sus fotos del producto , en versión desktop se ve bien pero en versión mobile se ven las 3 fotos en una misma fila, como puedo hacer para que en versión mobile se vea una foto debajo de otra?

Estuve probando con el plugin Make Tables Responsive : https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/make-tables-responsive/ pero no me funciona.

```
<figure class="wp-block-table">
<table class="">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center"><br><a href="http://www.midominio.com/carpeta1/">
                <strong>Categoria 1</strong><br><br><img class="wp-image-135" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.midominio.com/..../carpeta1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <br>descripción categoria 1
            </td>

            <td class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center"><br><a href="http://www.midominio.com/carpeta2/"><strong>Categoria 2</strong><br><br>
                <img class="wp-image-136" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.midominio.com/..../carpeta2.jpg" alt=""></a><br>
                    <br>descripción categoria 2
            </td>

            <td class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center"><br><a href="http://www.midominio.com/carpeta3/">
                <strong>Categoria3</strong><br><br><img class="wp-image-135" style="width: 150px;" src="http://www.midominio.com/..../carpeta3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                <br>descripción categoria 3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola paisanos. El tema que se os vea en una misma fila seguramente sea por el "display" que haya en la clase "wp-block-table" y es la que engloba todo. Este atributo lo debéis tener "inline" o "block" (no recuerdo cual es de los dos el que provoca esto). Si lo cambiais uno por el otro y refrescáis la página, debería funcionar...

Comment: Gracias Ferran acabo de probar-lo , en el css del theme hay un display:block y lo he cambiado por un display:inline pero no hace nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he solucionado con la extensión "Magic Liquidizer Responsive Table" para Wordpress